# @Transactional does not work when @Autowired applies

Tags: java, spring, transactions

I have written a sample application to test the annotated transaction management in Spring (@Transactional).

context file;

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-4.0.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-4.0.xsd">

<tx:annotation-driven />

<context:component-scan base-package="com.test" /> 

<bean id="playerService" class="com.test.service.PlayerServiceImpl" />

<bean id="jdbcTemplate" class="org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
</bean>

<bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceTransactionManager">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
</bean>

<bean id="dbUtil" class="com.test.util.DbUtil" init-method="initialize">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
</bean>

<bean id="dataSource" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
    <property name="driverClassName" value="${jdbc.driverClassName}" />
    <property name="url" value="${jdbc.url}" />
    <property name="username" value="${jdbc.username}" />
    <property name="password" value="${jdbc.password}" />
</bean>

<context:property-placeholder location="jdbc.properties"/>
```

PlayerDao bean

```
import com.test.model.Player;
import com.test.model.Team;

public interface PlayerDao {

public void insertPlayer(Player player);

public void insertTeam(Team team);

}
```

Implementation of PlayerDaoImpl

```
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Propagation;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional;

import com.test.model.Player;
import com.test.model.Team;

@Repository
public class PlayerDaoImpl implements PlayerDao{ 

    private JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate;

    @Autowired
    public void setDataSource(DataSource dataSource) {
        this.jdbcTemplate = new JdbcTemplate(dataSource);
    }

    @Transactional (propagation=Propagation.REQUIRED)
    public void insertPlayer(Player player){
        String insertSql ="INSERT INTO PLAYERS (PLAYER_NAME, DOB, AGE, TEAM_ID) VALUES(?,?,?,?);";

        jdbcTemplate.update(insertSql,new Object[]{player.getPlayerName(),player.getDob(), player.getAge(), player.getTeamId()});
    }

    @Transactional (propagation=Propagation.REQUIRED)
    public void insertTeam(Team team){
        String insertSql ="INSERT INTO TEAMS (TEAM_ID, TEAM_NAME) VALUES(?,?);";

        jdbcTemplate.update(insertSql,new Object[]{team.getTeamId(),team.getTeamName()});
    }

}
```

PlayerService

```
import com.test.model.Team;

public interface PlayerService {
    public void createTeam1(Team team) throws Exception;
    public void createTeam2(Team team) throws Exception;
}
```

PlayerService Implementation

```
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

import com.test.model.Team;
import com.test.persistence.PlayerDao;

@Service
public class PlayerServiceImpl implements PlayerService{

    @Autowired
    private  PlayerDao playerDao;

    public void createTeam1(Team team) throws Exception{
        playerDao.insertPlayer(team.getPlayers().get(0));
        playerDao.insertPlayer(team.getPlayers().get(1));
        playerDao.insertPlayer(team.getPlayers().get(2));
        playerDao.insertTeam(team);
    }

    public void createTeam2(Team team) throws Exception{
        playerDao.insertPlayer(team.getPlayers().get(0));
        playerDao.insertPlayer(team.getPlayers().get(1));

        playerDao.insertTeam(team);
        throw new Exception();
    }
}
```

The main class;

```
import java.time.LocalDate;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext;

import com.test.model.Player;
import com.test.model.Team;
import com.test.service.PlayerService;

public class TestMain {



    public static void main(String[] args) {

        ApplicationContext context = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("spring-config.xml");
        PlayerService playerService = (PlayerService) context.getBean("playerService");

        Team t1 = new Team();

        t1.setTeamId(1);
        t1.setTeamName("Team-1");

        Player p1 = new Player("Player 1", LocalDate.of(1981,05,02), 1);        
        Player p2 = new Player("Player 2", LocalDate.of(1983,02,15), 1);
        Player p3 = new Player("Player 3", LocalDate.of(1980,12,31), 1);

        List<Player> players1 = new ArrayList<Player>();
        players1.add(p1);
        players1.add(p2);
        players1.add(p3);

        t1.setPlayers(players1);

        Team t2 = new Team();

        t2.setTeamId(2);
        t2.setTeamName("Team-2");

        Player p4 = new Player("Player 4", LocalDate.of(1989,05,02), 1);
        Player p5 = new Player("Player 5", null, 1);

        List<Player> players2 = new ArrayList<Player>();
        players2.add(p4);
        players2.add(p5);

        t2.setPlayers(players2);

        try {
            playerService.createTeam1(t1);
            playerService.createTeam2(t2);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Transaction works well, when I set playerDao as one of the properties for the PlayerService in the context file as below (no @Autowired set for playerDao);

```
<bean id="playerService" class="com.slpl.service.PlayerServiceImpl" >
    <property name="playerDao" ref="playerDao" />
</bean>

<bean id="playerDao" class="com.slpl.persistence.PlayerDaoImpl">
    <property name="jdbcTemplate" ref="jdbcTemplate" />
</bean>
```

But, when I @Autowired playerDao to PlayerServiceImpl class, the transaction does not applies (transaction does not works).

What is the mistake I made here?

Comment: Your transaction should start at service level, it only starts at Dao. Mark Service as `@Tansactional`

Comment: Any specific reason to add @Transactional to service level?

Comment: Is creating team and player atomic operation? `throw new Exception()` in service method when your transaction starts and finishes in DAO will not cause a rollback. Btw what do you mean by "transaction does not works"? Do you get exception or no data in DB?

Comment: Your service method is the transactional boundary NOT the individual calls to the repositories. Now you have 7 individual transactions (4 for createTeam1 and 3 for createTeam2). So actually the behavior with `@Autowired` is the expected behavior.

Comment: Thanks @M.Deinum for the explanation. I greatly appreciate your explanation.

Answer (score 0):

This sample application is to demonstrate Spring transaction using annotation. createTeam1() method in PlayerServiceImpl class will create 3 players and a team. So, once it finished running, it will create 3 rows in the PLAYERS table and one row in the TEAMS table. The createTeam2() method is trying to create two players and a team. At the end of this method, it throws an exception which should rollback the players and team creation and MUST not create rows in the PLAYERS and TEAMS table.

Use of @Autowired annotation is correct for PlayerDao in the PlayerServiceImpl class. However, applying of transaction was incorrect. As @M.Deinum clearly explained current code create 7 separate transactions by applying transaction directly in the DAO methods (in this case insertPlayer() and insertTeam() methods). Therefore, correct way of applying transaction is at Service methods (createTeam1() and createTeam2() methods in this case).

In order to rollback the transaction upon throwing an exception, rollbackfor transaction attribute has to be set with correct exception (as a attribute for @Transactional annotation). Then spring transaction rollback the changes upon throwing an exception. Therefore, correct service method implementation as follows;

```
@Transactional (propagation=Propagation.REQUIRED, rollbackFor = {Exception.class})
public void createTeam1(Team team) throws Exception{
    playerDao.insertPlayer(team.getPlayers().get(0));
    playerDao.insertPlayer(team.getPlayers().get(1));
    playerDao.insertPlayer(team.getPlayers().get(2));
    playerDao.insertTeam(team);
}

@Transactional (propagation=Propagation.REQUIRED, rollbackFor = {Exception.class})
public void createTeam2(Team team) throws Exception{
    playerDao.insertPlayer(team.getPlayers().get(0));
    playerDao.insertPlayer(team.getPlayers().get(1));

    playerDao.insertTeam(team);
    throw new Exception();
}
```